# How do i use php to be able to allow a user to view another users profile

Tags: php

i am creating a social network, when i first created my search bar for names i worked out well but when i click on any name it takes me to the profile of who ever is logged in here is my php code for my search bar

```
?php
include 'func.inc.php';
if (isset($_POST['full_name'])) {
  $first_names = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['full_name']));

  $errors = array();

if (empty($first_names)) {
   $errors[] = 'Please enter a search term';
} else if (strlen($first_names)<3) {
   $errors[] = 'Your search term must be three or more charecters';
} else if (search_results($first_names) === false) {
   $errors[] = 'Your search for '.$first_names.' returned no results';
}

?>  
<?php
if (empty($errors)) {
 $results = search_results($first_names);
 $results_num = count($results);

 echo '<div align="center"> <p>Your search for <strong>', $first_names, '</strong> returned <strong>', $results_num, '</strong> results</p> </div>';

 foreach($results as $result) {
    echo '<h3> <strong> <div align="center"> <a href="profile job.php?user_id=', $result['user_id'],'"> ', $result['first_name'],' ', $result['last_name'], '</a><br> ', $result['address'],'</div> </strong> </h3>';
  }
 }
}
?>  
here is func.inc.php
<?php
include 'db.inc.php'; 

function search_results($first_names) { 
 $returned_results = array();
 $where = "";

$first_names = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $first_names);
$total_first_names = count($first_names);

foreach($first_names as $key=>$first_name) {
  $where .= "`full_name` LIKE '%$first_name%'";
  if ($first_name != ($total_first_names - 1)) {
  $where .= " AND ";
  }
 }

$results = "SELECT `user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name` FROM `users` WHERE $where";
$results_num = ($results = mysql_query($results)) ? mysql_num_rows($results) : 0;

if ($results_num === 0) {
  return false;
 } else {

     while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
      $returned_results[] = array(
       'first_name' => $results_row['first_name'],
       'last_name' => $results_row['last_name'],
       'user_id' => $results_row['user_id']\
      ); 
     }

     return $returned_results;
   }

}   

?>
```

and please explain it in detail im not that good with this email me if anything at philipnagel511@gmail.com

Comment: User should have it's own unique uid , right? I don't think there should be problem if you're correct on it. When getting the user details user_id should be enough for your reference.

Comment: you should post the code for your profile page. You are probably not using the get variable user_id to pull the relevant profile. But since you're early in the game, please switch to mysqli or PDO while you can. If you have any hope for your social network it should be at least kind of current

Comment: I think it is not a good practice to add your email here. Why don't you just view this page frequently?